# Bootstrapp datetime picker component js displaying in a weird way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

trying to apply this js component to my project, I'm having the following issue when displaying the calendar

[image]

It is showing weird codes where days and months are supposed to be... Any idea how can I solve this? I'm working in a aspx file with html, css3, jquery and .net

this is the code I'm trying with:

```
                                   <div style="overflow:hidden;">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                                <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            $(function () {
                                                $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
                                                    inline: true,
                                                    sideBySide: true
                                                });
                                            });
                                        </script>
                                 </div>
```

styles and js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<link href="path/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by weird codes?

Comment: Pretty hard to help you when you provide no code, screenshots, details, etc.

Comment: Might have something to do with file encoding, specially since you're using asp.net

Comment: Not sure what versions of everything you're using, but the code seems to work fine for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/29g7brb9/

Comment: Put `<meta charset="utf8">` in your html head

Comment: utf8 is already set